# Managing two editable fields in gutenberg

Tags: plugin-development, block-editor

I'm building a gutenberg block plugin which takes two fields, a DOI name and a title. I can manage one successfully, but I'm not sure how to edit/save two at the same time. So far I have:

```
( function( blocks, components, i18n, element, _ ) {
const el = element.createElement;
const editable = blocks.Editable;
const __ = i18n.__;

blocks.registerBlockType( 'doib/doi', {
    title: __( 'DOI', 'doib' ),
    icon: 'id',
    category: 'widgets',
    attributes: {
        doi: {
            type: 'string',
        },
        title: {
            type: 'string',
        },
    },
    supports: {
        html: false,
    },
    edit: function( props ) {
        const focus = props.focus;

        function onChangeDOI( updated ) {
            props.setAttributes( { doi: updated } );
        }

        return (
            el(
                editable,
                {
                    className: props.className,
                    value: props.attributes.doi,
                    placeholder: __( 'Enter DOI name. Takes the form of "10.1000/xyz123".' ),
                    onChange: onChangeDOI,
                    focus: focus,
                    onFocus: props.setFocus,
                },
            )
        );
    },
    save: function( props ) {
        return (
            el( 'div', { className: props.className, dataDoi: props.attributes.doi },
                props.attributes.doi,
            )
        );
    },
} );
}(
    window.wp.blocks,
    window.wp.components,
    window.wp.i18n,
    window.wp.element
) );
```

And I'm not too sre how to proceed beyonf this point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Editable` has been replaced with `RichText` in 2.2.

Here's a example of two RichText components being edit/saved together:

```
const { __ } = wp.i18n;
const {
    registerBlockType,
    RichText,
} = wp.blocks;

registerBlockType( 'wtv/wtv', {
    title: __( 'wtv', 'wtv' ),
    icon: 'id',
    category: 'widgets',
    keywords: [ __( 'wtv' ), __( 'wtv' ), __( 'wtv' ) ],
    attributes: {
        doi: {
            type: 'string',
            selector: '.doi',
            default: '',
        },
        title: {
            type: 'string',
            selector: '.title',
            default: '',
        },
    },
    edit( { attributes, setAttributes, className } ) {
        const onChangeDOI = value => {
            setAttributes( { doi: value } );
        };
        const onChangeTitle = value => {
            setAttributes( { title: value } );
        };
        return (
            <div className={ className } >
                <RichText
                    tagname="div"
                    placeholder="Enter DOI name. Takes .."
                    value={ attributes.doi }
                    onChange={ onChangeDOI }
                />
                <RichText
                    tagname="div"
                    placeholder="Title .."
                    value={ attributes.title }
                    onChange={ onChangeTitle }
                />
            </div>
        );
    },
    save: function( props ) {
        return ( <div className={ props.className } >
            <div className="doi">
                { props.attributes.doi }
            </div>
            <div className="title">
                { props.attributes.title }
            </div>
        </div> );
    },
} );
```

I apologize my answer isn't in es5, but its so much easier in ESNext (highly recommend using [@ahmadawais create-guten-block](https://github.com/ahmadawais/create-guten-block) for the tooling)